# Check if OneToOneField is None in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one

I have two models like this:

```
class Type1Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    ...


class Type2Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    ...
```

I need to do something if the user has Type1 or Type2 profile:

```
if request.user.type1profile != None:
    # do something
elif request.user.type2profile != None:
    # do something else
else:
    # do something else
```

But, for users that don't have either type1 or type2 profiles, executing code like that produces the following error:

```
Type1Profile matching query does not exist.
```

How can I check the type of profile a user has?

Thanks

Answer (score 108):

To check if the (OneToOne) relation exists or not, you can use the `hasattr` function:

```
if hasattr(request.user, 'type1profile'):
    # do something
elif hasattr(request.user, 'type2profile'):
    # do something else
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Unfortunately, this doesn't work all the time. In case you want to work with `select_related()` now or in the future -- or maybe even to be sure you also handle other sorts of magic which may happen elsewhere -- you have to extend the test as follows: `if hasattr(object, 'onetoonerevrelattr') and object.onetoonerevrelattr != None`

Comment: Note that in Python < 3.2, `hasattr` will swallow *all* exceptions that happen during the database lookup, and not just `DoesNotExist`. This is probably broken, and not what you want.

Comment: not working with python 2.7. Even if OneToOne doesn't exist, it return a django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object.

Comment: @alartur what django version are you using?

Comment: Django 1.5. But I solved my particular issue by implementing what I wanted to do in a whole different way.

Comment: For Python 3.2+ this no longer works.  See the next-highest comment on this question at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240021/1048705

Comment: Note that `request.user` is a different case than other OneToOne relationships, because `request.user` is a `SimpleLazyObject`

Answer (score 52):

It's possible to see if a nullable one-to-one relationship is null for a particular model simply by testing the corresponding field on the model for `None`ness, but *only* if you test on the model where the one-to-one relationship originates. For example, given these two classes…

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(models.Model):  # The class where the one-to-one originates
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, blank=True, null=True)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

… to see if a `Restaurant` has a `Place`, we can use the following code:

```
>>> r = Restaurant(serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
>>> r.save()
>>> if r.place is None:
>>>    print "Restaurant has no place!"
Restaurant has no place!
```

To see if a `Place` has a `Restaurant`, it's important to understand that referencing the `restaurant` property on an instance of `Place` raises a `Restaurant.DoesNotExist` exception if there is no corresponding restaurant. This happens because Django performs a lookup internally using `QuerySet.get()`. For example:

```
>>> p2 = Place(name='Ace Hardware', address='1013 N. Ashland')
>>> p2.save()
>>> p2.restaurant
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
DoesNotExist: Restaurant matching query does not exist.
```

In this scenario, Occam's razor prevails, and the best approach for making a determination about whether or not a `Place` has a `Restautrant` would be a standard `try` / `except` construct as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get).

```
>>> try:
>>>     restaurant = p2.restaurant
>>> except Restaurant.DoesNotExist:
>>>     print "Place has no restaurant!"
>>> else:
>>>     # Do something with p2's restaurant here.
```

While joctee's suggestion to use `hasattr` works in practice, it really only works by accident since `hasattr` suppresses *all* exceptions (including `DoesNotExist`) as opposed to just `AttributeError`s, like it should. As [Pi Delport](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444705/) pointed out, this behavior was actually corrected in Python 3.2 per the following ticket: http://bugs.python.org/issue9666. Furthermore — and at the risk of sounding opinionated — I believe the above `try` / `except` construct is more representative of how Django works, while using `hasattr` can cloud the issue for newbies, which may create FUD and spread bad habits.

**EDIT** [Don Kirkby's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794/) reasonable compromise also seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 25):

I like [joctee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016298/4794), because it's so simple.

```
if hasattr(request.user, 'type1profile'):
    # do something
elif hasattr(request.user, 'type2profile'):
    # do something else
else:
    # do something else
```

Other commenters have raised concerns that it may not work with certain versions of Python or Django, but [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) shows this technique as one of the options:

> You can also use hasattr to avoid the need for exception catching:

```
>>> hasattr(p2, 'restaurant')
False
```

Of course, the documentation also shows the exception catching technique:

> p2 doesn’t have an associated restaurant:

```
>>> from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
>>> try:
>>>     p2.restaurant
>>> except ObjectDoesNotExist:
>>>     print("There is no restaurant here.")
There is no restaurant here.
```

I agree with [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240021/4794) that catching the exception makes it clearer what's happening, but it just seems messier to me. Perhaps this is a reasonable compromise?

```
>>> print(Restaurant.objects.filter(place=p2).first())
None
```

This is just querying the `Restaurant` objects by place. It returns `None` if that place has no restaurant.

Here's an executable snippet for you to play with the options. If you have Python, Django, and SQLite3 installed, it should just run. I tested it with Python 3.8.10 and Django 4.0.2.

```
""" Django models in a single, runnable file.

Based on Nsukami's blog post: https://nskm.xyz/posts/dsfp/

To get it running, copy it into a directory named udjango:
$ pip install django
$ python udjango_models.py

Tested with Django 4.0 and Python 3.8.
"""
import logging
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

NAME = 'udjango'
DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'


def main():
    setup()

    class Place(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s the place" % self.name

    class Restaurant(models.Model):
        place = models.OneToOneField(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
        serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

    class Waiter(models.Model):
        restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s the waiter at %s" % (self.name, self.restaurant)

    syncdb(Place)
    syncdb(Restaurant)
    syncdb(Waiter)

    p1 = Place(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
    p1.save()
    p2 = Place(name='Ace Hardware', address='1013 N. Ashland')
    p2.save()
    r = Restaurant(place=p1, serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
    r.save()

    print(r.place)
    print(p1.restaurant)

    # Option 1: try/except
    try:
        print(p2.restaurant)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print("There is no restaurant here.")

    # Option 2: getattr and hasattr
    print(getattr(p2, 'restaurant', 'There is no restaurant attribute.'))
    if hasattr(p2, 'restaurant'):
        print('Restaurant found by hasattr().')
    else:
        print('Restaurant not found by hasattr().')

    # Option 3: a query
    print(Restaurant.objects.filter(place=p2).first())


def setup():
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'WARN'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "WARN"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)

main()
```

Comment: The docs may be incorrect, as hasattr does not work for me even in Django 4.0/Python 3.8, it returns true but the attribute evaluates to None when there is no relationship.

Comment: Have you tried it with my example, @bparker? I updated it to Django 4.0, and `hasattr()` still works for me.

Answer (score 10):

How about using try/except blocks?

```
def get_profile_or_none(user, profile_cls):

    try:
        profile = getattr(user, profile_cls.__name__.lower())
    except profile_cls.DoesNotExist:
        profile = None

    return profile
```

Then, use like this!

```
u = request.user
if get_profile_or_none(u, Type1Profile) is not None:
    # do something
elif get_profile_or_none(u, Type2Profile) is not None:
    # do something else
else:
    # d'oh!
```

I suppose you could use this as a generic function to get any reverse OneToOne instance, given an originating class (here: your profile classes) and a related instance (here: request.user).

Answer (score 3):

Use `select_related`!

```
>>> user = User.objects.select_related('type1profile').get(pk=111)
>>> user.type1profile
None
```

Comment: I know it works like this, but is this behaviour of select_related actually documented?

Comment: I just tried this in Django 1.9.2, and it raises `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 3):

in case you have the Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
```

And you just need to know for any User that UserProfile exists/or not - the **most efficient way** from the database point of view to use **exists query**.

Exists query will return just boolean, rather than *reverse attribute access* like `hasattr(request.user, 'type1profile')` - which will generate **get query** and return full object representation

To do it - you need to add a property to the User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser)

@property
def has_profile():
    return UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.pk).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the **smart approaches** will be to add **custom** field **OneToOneOrNoneField** and **use** it [works for Django >=1.9]

```
from django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors import ReverseOneToOneDescriptor
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import models


class SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone(ReverseOneToOneDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().__get__(*args, **kwargs)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None


class OneToOneOrNoneField(models.OneToOneField):
    """A OneToOneField that returns None if the related object doesn't exist"""
    related_accessor_class = SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('null', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('blank', True)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Implementation**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):  # The class where the one-to-one originates
    place = OneToOneOrNoneField(Place)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

**Usage**

```
r = Restaurant(serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
r.place  # will return None
```

Comment: for django 1.8 you need to use `SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` instead of `ReverseOneToOneDescriptor` like this 
```from django.db.models.fields.related import SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a combination of has_attr and is None:

```
class DriverLocation(models.Model):
    driver = models.OneToOneField(Driver, related_name='location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Driver(models.Model):
    pass

    @property
    def has_location(self):
        return not hasattr(self, "location") or self.location is None
```